# Comparing data from multiple sheets in excel - VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently working with a spreadsheet that has three sheets and fixed column names. The columns can move, however, meaning I need to determine a way to find the column by name instead of by column number. I have tried to do this using .Find method I have seen on other StackOverflow posts - but I get a 'Compile Error: Object Required'

```
Private Sub Calculation_Click()

Dim sheet1 As Worksheet
Dim sheet2 As Worksheet
Dim sheet3 As Worksheet

'Sheets assigned variable names
Set sheet1 = Sheets("Market_price")
Set sheet2 = Sheets("Reference_data")
Set sheet3 = Sheets("Dividends")

'adaptive column finder
Dim ticker1 As String
Dim ticker2 As String
Dim ticker3 As String
Dim aCell1 As Range
Dim aCell2 As Range
Dim aCell3 As Range

ticker1 = "Ticker"
ticker2 = "Ticker"
ticker3 = "Ticker"

Set aCell1 = sheet1.Rows(1).Find(What:=ticker1, LookIn:=xlValues, _
    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
Set aCell2 = sheet2.Rows(1).Find(What:=ticker2, LookIn:=xlValues, _
    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
Set aCell3 = sheet3.Rows(1).Find(What:=ticker3, LookIn:=xlValues, _
    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    
Set ticker1ColNum = aCell1.column



MsgBox ticker1ColNum

End Sub
```

I am trying to do this for multiple columns on multiple sheets that have the same names so I can compare the values in those columns.

Thanks for any advice at all.

Comment: Which line throws the error?

Comment: You don't declare `ticker1ColNum` but if it should be a number remove the `Set` from that line. Also check first that the value is found to avoid aRTE.

Comment: @SJR's comment should be the actual answer. aCell1.column is not an object so you cannot use "Set" to assign its value.

Comment: I am not sure which line threw the error - but adding this fixed it

```If Not aCell1 Is Nothing Then
    ticker1ColNum = aCell1.column
End If

If Not aCell2 Is Nothing Then
    ticker2ColNum = aCell2.column
End If

If Not aCell3 Is Nothing Then
    ticker3ColNum = aCell3.column
End If